# Javascript ParseInt with positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, string, parseint

```
String x = "{"val" : 34, "gain": -23}"
```

How can I get the positve or negative number out of string. I am trying:

```
x.split("gain")[1]; // returns something like " : -23

parseInt(x.split("gain")[1]); // returns NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest thing you should do is parse JSON and access value

```js
let x = `{"val" : 34, "gain": -23}`

console.log(JSON.parse(x).gain)
```

You need to change the string to parse able state by removing anything which is not a valid number before parsing it with `parseInt`

```
[^+-\d]+
```

This above pattern means match anything except `+, - or any digit` and then we replace matched value by empty string

```js
let x = `{"val" : 34, "gain": -23}`.split("gain")[1]

console.log(parseInt(x.replace(/[^+-\d]+/g,'')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't you want to use `JSON.parse(x)['gain']` ?

```js
let x = `{"val" : 34, "gain": -23}`
let gain = JSON.parse(x)['gain'];

console.log(gain);
```

Answer (score 1):

String x = "{"val" : 34, "gain": -23}"

How can I get the positve or negative number out of string. I am trying:

x.split("gain")[1]; // returns something like " : -23 parseInt(x.split("gain")[1]); // returns NaN

Replace : and trim string

```
let s = x.split("gain")[1].replace(":", "").trim();

parseInt(s);
```

Or

Change the x value to a proper object

```
let x = { val : 34, gain : - 23}
```

Then get gain as in `x.gain` this will return - 23